# VBA - Automatically populating table with specific data from other table

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables, one with all the information of my project and another that displays the expired or almost-expired rows from the master table.

What I'm trying to do is have the Expired table update with all of the expired variables form the master table every time the worksheet is opened.

The problem I'm facing is that when using a For Loop it adds many empty cells before adding the next value to the Expired table.

Code for Expired-Table:

```
    Private Sub warning_list()
    Dim wsExp As Worksheet: Set wsExp = Worksheets("EXPIRED_LIST")
    Dim wsList As Worksheet: Set wsList = Worksheets("LIST")
    Dim digsafe As String
    Dim exp_date As Date
    Dim time_left As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim warning_val As String: warning_val = "OK"
    Dim warning_tbl As ListObject: Set warning_tbl = wsExp.ListObjects("Table3")
    Dim warning_or As ListRow
    Dim list_tbl As ListObject: Set list_tbl = wsList.ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim list_or As ListRow

    Set warning_or = warning_tbl.ListRows.Add

    For i = 1 To wsList.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If wsList.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 24).Value = warning_val Then
            digsafe = list_tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
            exp_date = list_tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 2).Value

            warning_or.Range(1, 1).Value = digsafe
            warning_or.Range(1, 2).Value = exp_date

        End If
    Next i


End Sub
```

EDIT:
I also have the following code to automatically run the macro.

```
'Action whenever sheet is opened
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   Call warning_list
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to add it so it pastes data on next blank row in table?

Comment: You could create a `pivot table`, using the "complete" table as data source. Then, just filter-it by adding a conditional test

Comment: An alternative solution to the conditional test, is to create a last row in yout "complete" table, saying if it's expired or no. You can use the `"=IF("` function to test it. Then, filter just the rows which has "YES" on the expired column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution to a VBA Macro, is to create a last column in your "complete" table, saying if it's expired or no. You can use the `=IF(` function to test it. Then, filter just the rows which has "YES" on the expired column, using a `PIVOT TABLE`

[image]

Comment: This is a great alternative. Haven't used Pivot tables, but I see how they are so powerful. Thank you.

Comment: How would I add the Address to the pivot table as a column? When I place it in values it displays the sum of addresses. @germano_lodi

Comment: You have to set the "Row Labels" as each one of the references (in my image, the "Name" field), the Expiry Date as Value and the Expired(YES/NO) as a Filter